# Compare two tables for discrepencies

Tags: sql-server-2016, data, sqlcompare

I am trying to compare two tables in two separate databases (same instance)
for a new data extract
The tables have around 4 millions rows and due to how they've been extracted are not in the same order in each table, as they are just staging tables (there is no PKs).

I have tried using
(select * from table 1
Except
select * from table 2)
UNION ALL
(select * from table 2
Except
select * from table 1)
however this results in around 10 millions rows so is not working as expected.

I would guess the results should be around a few thousand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the records are unique in each table you can do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 FROM (
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 FROM TABLE1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 FROM TABLE2) SUBSEL
GROUP BY FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to define your primary key - one or several fields what will unique identify the record. All fields as primary key is possible but not recommended

Second, you have to decide what you mean as 'compare':

- records exists in first table but not in second
- records exists in both tables but has difference in non primary key fields
- records exists in the second table only

Comment: The problem with defining a primary key is none of the columns can be made unique there are 14 columns in total, there are some like reference / surname etc. that would normally be ideally for a PK but there are duplicates because if all 14 columns are not exact match the system enters a new row.
It is not our data we extract it from a 3rd party so don't have control of the input system

Comment: Since your query returned ALL records in both datasets I guess you missed field order. Try to use field names instead of star. Try to limit queries with WHERE clause instead of all records. Your query looks correct